# center a spinner in a button

Tags: html, css, pug

I am trying to center a spinner in a button. The spinner will appear while the system is getting a response. I have changed margins and padding and the changes show when I inspect element, but it just adds margin and padding to the bottom without moving the spinner further up within the button.

Here is my Jade:

```
div.form-group
    div.col-sm-4
        button.form-control.btn.btn-success.strong-button(type='submit' ng-model='pressed' ng-disabled="pressed") Delete
            spinner(ng-show="submitDelete")
```

The css for spinner is

```
.font-awesome-spinner{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The spinner element creates a div inside the button element that looks like (taken from page source)

```
<button (all the stuff here)>
     <div class="font-awesome-spinner ng-isolate-scope" ng-show="submitDelete">
          <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"
               ::before
          </i>
     </div>
</button>
```

Comment: Could you please include css and any other libraries for your issue?

Comment: Yea I made this simple plunkr and its centered automatically http://plnkr.co/edit/qwnyBU47UhGPVS3zdfN0, Can you update it with what you're doing to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @KevinF Since you put the spinner with no text, I tried mine with no text. sure enough, it worked. I added a span to the button to hold the button text and then I hide it when the spinner comes up. That centers the spinner.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot center a block element like a DIV with `text-align: center;` Set the width of your spinner div and then add `margin: auto;` to the spinner div.

Also your HTML is malformed. Check `(all the stuff here)` in your button element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #button_element {
      width: 100px;
    }
    #button_element .font-awesome-spinner {
      width: 50px;
      margin: auto;
    }
  </stlye>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="button_element">
    <div class="font-awesome-spinner ng-isolate-scope" ng-show="submitDelete">
      <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>
    </div>
  </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the (all the stuff here) is just for brevity on SO. The Jade generates the HTML with the classes etc... required